# Salvar Perguntas

Tags: suporte, favoritos

É possível salvar alguma questões que eu tenha interesse para pesquisas posteriores?

Gostaria de salvar algumas questões através do próprio stackoverflow, junto a minha conta em uma seção do tipo "questões de interesse".

Answer (score 8):

Abaixo de cada questão tem um desenho de uma estrela, clicando nele você irá salvar está questão:

[image: favoritar questão]

Após favoritar todas questões desejadas, vá no seu perfil, clicando em na barra superior e em cima da sua foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Geralmente você já estará na aba Participação, mas se não estiver clique nela:

[image: aba perfil participação]

Em seguida vá mais para o meio da página e procure a aba Favoritos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta aba irá aparecer todas questões salvas, você poderá ordenar por:

- votos (a partir da que teve mais votos)
- atividade (a partir da que teve atividade mais recente)
- recentes (pela pergunta mais nova)
- visitas (pelo numero de visitas)
- adicionado (pela da que você adicionou)