# Organização dos favoritos

Tags: debate, favoritos

Eu ainda tenho poucas perguntas salvas como **favoritas**, mas pelas poucas que tenho já criei uma bagunça, com uma lista que contem diversas categorias.

Segundo este [Tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4017/salvar-perguntas/), no site temos as seguintes formas de organizar os favoritos :

- votos (a partir da que teve mais votos)
- atividade (a partir da que teve atividade mais recente)
- recentes (pela pergunta mais nova)
- visitas (pelo numero de visitas)
- adicionado (pela da que você adicionou)

**Seria possível Organizar meus favoritos pelo tema?**

Por exemplo estou estudando os conceitos de Web Service, e vi no site um monte de perguntas interessante sobre o assunto, seria possível no site eu organizar pelo tema **Web Service**?

Comment: Isto já foi solicitado diversas vezes e sempre foi declinado, sem um motivo forte. É uma pena, o jeito é favoritar externamente do jeito que deseja.

Comment: Ok , eu devo remover o tópico então ?

Comment: Acho que não, sempre podemos ter novas informações sobre isto. No mínimo fica como referência em português, que acho que não tem ainda.

Comment: O mais próximo disso hoje é fazer uma pesquisa com argumento `infavorites:mine` filtrar por alguma tag e por um texto, já dá uma boa ajuda na hora de procurar algo especifico. Exemplo: `[php]infavorites:mine sqlstate 2400`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Você pode pesquisar nos seus favoritos por tag. No campo de busca, digite:

```
[nome-da-tag] infavorites:mine
```

Eu também acho que seria ótimo poder organizar livremente os favoritos, em grupos. Porém isso foi sugerido várias vezes na rede e é sempre rejeitado.

Comment: Legal que dar para pesquisar no favorito dos outros, é só pegar o id do usuário, né @bfavaretto: Exemplo: `[css] infavorites:74`. Hehe.

Comment: Hehe, pra você ver a zona que são meus favoritos, tem de tudo lá @Fernando

Answer (score 5):

Certa vez, escrevi um JS/HTML para consultar a [**API**](https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api) e listar/filtrar os favoritos usando Isotope e fiz uma page no GitHub. É só selecionar o site e colocar o ID do usuário para puxar seus favoritos. O armazenamento dos usuários/favoritos é via `localStorage`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[online](http://brasofilo.github.io/stack.favs/)</kbd> <sub>.</sub> [<kbd>repositório</kbd>](https://github.com/brasofilo/stack.favs)

Não estou fazendo SPAM do meu código pois está ali parado tem tempo. Com certeza, não vou mexer nisso no futuro próximo, é só ficar à vontade para fazer o que quiser com isso.

Estava estudando Isotope e provavelmente terá algum bug; a consulta à API, armazenamento e a filtragem básica funcionam.

Comment: Muito bom ! obrigado pela dica . desse modo está perfeito esquenta não rs , acredito que pode ser útil para muitas pessoas., agradeço sua atenção =D.