# Filtrando perguntas com condições especificas

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de aperfeiçoar a forma de filtragem das perguntas , para dar atenção a perguntas não respondidas ou as que precisam de atenção de uma forma mais eficiente.

Percebi de acordo com a resposta desse [tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4942/28666) que existem algumas *palavras chaves* que possibilitam a filtragem de conteúdo aqui no site.

- **Esse tipo de informação somente os usuários moderadores tem acesso ?**
- **Existe algum guia para utilizar essas palavras chaves ?**

Comment: Qualquer um pode usar, a referência sobre assunto é [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualquer um pode usar essas opções para filtro. A explicação para cada item está na central de ajuda, nosso modelo > [como fazer uma busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Um exemplo para buscar apenas perguntas sem respostas de uma tag especifica:

```
[nome]answers:0
```